# Define which attribute to work on by passing it as an argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have class that has two attributes of same type.

The class currently have two methods doing the same thing, one for each attribute.

Is it possible to reduce these two methods to only one by passing the attribute name as an argument?

This is what I have tried (but gives me "NoMethodError: undefined method `attribute_name' for ..."):

```
def my_method(attribute_name)
  self.attribute_name = 2
  self.save
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save without validation:

```ruby
  update_attribute(attribute_name.to_sym, 2)
```

To save with validation:

```ruby
  update_attributes({ attribute_name.to_sym => 2 })
```

To assign without saving:

```ruby
  assign_attributes({ attribute_name.to_sym => 2 })
```

I think the last method is what are you looking for

```ruby
def my_method(attribute_name)
  self.assign_attributes({ attribute_name.to_sym => 2 })
  self.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Aliasing would be a better option instead of assigning attribute values as you've attempted.  Take a look at the usage of [`alias_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute) or [`alias_method`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method)

As far as the error is concerned, you cannot use attributes as variables as you've used.  You can instead make use of [`send`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) as follows:

```
def my_method(attribute_name)
  send(:"#{attribute_name}=", 2)
  save
end
```